# Excel Formula for Inventory

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I'm new to the excel formula, so I don't know all the functions. I'm trying to create a formula using Vlookup or something akin to it for my inventory excel sheet.

I should be able to enter a serial number(possibly only the new version), where it will search up in the table.

---

## Header

```
Date | Serial # (new) | Model (new) | Serial # (old) | Model (old) | Department | Assign | Building | Office | Deploy | Transfer | Status | Note |
```

## Example

```
Mar-14 | CK9UZA2 | 7060 | 9XUUA56 | 9030 AIO | Finance | Bell Thompson | Sky Hall | Sky 420 | Yes | No | Completed | Added to the Inventory list
```

## Result

- New Serial # (reference cell): CK9UZA2
- Date: Mar-14
- Department: Finance
- Building: Sky Hall
- Office: Sky 420
- Assign to: Bell Thompson
- Old Serial #: 9XUUA56
- Old Model: 9030 AIO
- Deploy: Yes
- Transfer: No
- Status: Completed
- Notes: Added to the Inventory list

Any assistance will be helpful, especially if someone can breakdown for me for future reference

Comment: Index and Match are your way to go I think :)

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, looking up values can be done in several ways (e.g.: `VLOOKUP`and `HLOOKUP`), however a very powerful combination can be made using `INDEX` and `MATCH`, being at least as fast as other functions and at best much faster.

---

***[`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)***

The `INDEX` function function returns a value or the reference to a value from within a table or range and has got the following parameters:

- An array of cells (matrix) which is required
- An index number of the row we want to return a value from which is required
- An index number of the column we want to return a value from which is optional

So the syntax would look like: `=INDEX(RangeOfCells,RowIndex,[ColumnIndex])`

---

***[`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)***

The `MATCH` function searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range. It has got the following parameters:

- A lookup value which is required
- A lookup array of cells (matrix) which is required
- A match type (-1,0,1) which is optional (automatically type 1 if omitted)

So the syntax would look like: `=MATCH(LookupValue,LookupArray,[MatchType])`

---

***`INDEX` + `MATCH`***

Let's imagine a simple dataset in `Sheet1` like the following:

```
| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| ID1     | A       | Val1    | Month1  |
| ID2     | B       | Val2    | Month2  |
| ID3     | C       | Val3    | Month3  |
| ID4     | D       | Val4    | Month4  |
| ID5     | E       | Val5    | Month5  |
```

And the following setup to search for a value in `Sheet2`:

```
| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| ID3     |         |         |         |
```

Now if you are interested in the value of `Header2` up to `Header4` by looking up a specific value under `Header1` you can apply the following technique in `B2` and drag right.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$D,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),COLUMN(A1))
```

The result will look like:

```
| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| ID3     | C       | Val3    | Month3  |
```

If you take into consideration the above about `INDEX` and `MATCH` you can see that I gave `INDEX` it's required array of cells (1st parameter), used `MATCH` to return a row index number (2nd parameter) and have utilized the `COLUMN` function along with a relative cell reference to return the column index number (3rd parameter).

The `MATCH` function has been given a lookup value (1st parameter), a lookup array (2nd parameter) and I have used match type 0, which tells the function to look for an exact match.

---

***[`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)***

In this specific case it would have been possible to utilize the `VLOOKUP` function. But I'll try to set out why I would prefer the `INDEX` + `MATCH` combination:

- `VLOOKUP` gives you little flexibility as the lookup value must sit in the left-most column of your lookup matrix, whereas `INDEX` gives you the option to return any column through the third parameter.
- As previously mentioned, while `VLOOKUP` is the more popular option, `INDEX` + `MATCH` is the faster option. If you go for speed, then use this!

---

***Further notes:***

While this was just a simple breakdown of how you could use the combination of `INDEX` + `MATCH`, there are a few more things to consider:

- In the example above I used absolute, semi-absolute and relative cell references (note the differences with the `$` sign). Utilize this technique to be able to drag a formula to the right, left, bottom or top.
- Set up a table instead of a matrix. You can refer to columns within that table instead of full columns. Searching only a few rows compared to all possible rows in a column is always (AFAIK) faster!
- When you get more advanced you'll notice `INDEX` and `MATCH` is something that will appear as a lifesafer much more often in many ways :)
- While looking for an exact match, `MATCH` might return an error when the lookup value simply isn't found. This is something to consider when you see any `#N/A` error. A workaround is a `ISNA` or `IFERROR` function within the formula.

I hope that gets you started! Check the links I included for some more in-depth information.