# How to compare multiple values from different columns in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some difficulties with my IF formula.
I have the following columns that represent some subjects and the points that I managed to get for those subjects (F:H). In column I , I would like to compare my points with another table(M:N) that contains the minimum amount of points needed to pass the course .If my score is equal or greater then what the corresponding score is in column N, I would like to show PASS or FAIL in column I.
I Used the following formula but when comparing with M:N it keeps going down (outside the table) giving me in the end all the exams as passed.

```
 =IF(AND(F2:$F$6=M2:$M$6)&H2:$H$6>=N2:$N6;"PASS";"FAIL")

F                 H            I                      M                     N
(Subjects)       (Points)                          (Subjects)              (Points to Pass)
Mathematics       85                            Mathematics                 85
English           88                             English                    70
French            78                             French                     60
Chinese           56                             Chinese                    60
Physics           70                             Sports                     80
Sports            95                             Physics                    80
```

Comment: Use `INDEX` and `MATCH`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194)  is some explaination on how to use that combination of powerful functions. Or else a simple `SUMIF` to reference your value against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

`=IF(H2>=VLOOKUP(F2,$M$2:$N$7,2,FALSE),"PASS","FAIL")`

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Example formula should look like this:

```
=IF(H1>=INDEX($N$1:$N$6,MATCH(F1,$M$1:$M$6,0)),"PASS","FAIL")
```

Comment: @JvdV I'm just promoting the best practice :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let your table layout housed in `F1:N7` include header

In `I2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(H2>=VLOOKUP(F2,M:N,2,0),"PASS","FAIL")
```