# Excel: VLOOKUP and FIND combinations

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am not very familiar with Excel functions and I need some advice on the following problem.

I have two  worksheets called `List1` and `List2`, which help me with ordering goods for my shop.

I want to find the exact keyword in `List1` column B, e.g **car**, "read" the corresponding value from column C, then find the same word in `List2` and return the value in column C. I am open to solutions using `macro`, `script`, or `excel formula`.

[image: Something like this]

I tried to solve it with **VLOOKUP** function in `List2` but the data is from my supplier so it's in different order and he may change or add some new rows in it sometimes and i must always copy the function from the previous version of the file one by one and paste them to the new one. The table contains more than 3,000 items but I am only ordering something like 200.

Thanks in advance, for any help...

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(list1.$c$2:$c$7,MATCH(list2.c2,list1.$A$1:$A$6,0))
```

Comment: Yes, index with match is the way to go =)

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much HimaTech.

Comment: @DarioG please use the "tick" or "check" mark to accept the answer, otherwise the system cannot account for it properly.