# Get excel columns where column x is in other spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I want to get some columns from one spreadsheet to another base on equability of columns.
For example:

- In the first sheet I have list of employees where column A is employee ID and column B is their name.
- In the second sheet I have list of employees details where column A is employee ID and column B address and C is second address.

There might be employee IDs on the first spreadsheet that doesn't exists in the second spreadsheet and vice versa.
I need the right formula to put in a new column in the first spreadsheet to fill it with the first/second employee's address based on the ID on the same line.

Hope I make sense.

Comment: It does make sense, and you'll need to look into `INDEX` and `MATCH` to retrieve those results. Have a look at this older post I made to try and simplify the procedure to set it up: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194)

Comment: Match return the wrong line `=match(A2,A:A)` return 67 which isn't like the `A2`. Maybe the '\' char in the string has anything to do with it?

Comment: The match returns the index of the value in the array you feed it. So if the value is found in the first element it returns 1 etc. Despite if it's on row 5. So then Index comes into play to return the correct result.

Comment: The thing is that it gives wrong location, i.e the cells doesn't match.

Comment: Issue sorted by sorting the vector range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this formula in cell `C2` of your first sheet:

```
=LOOKUP(A2;Sheet!A:A;Sheet2!B:B)
```

Then the `address` (column B) should be returned. change `B:B` for `C:C` and it will return the second address.

To found out if the ID does exists in `Sheet2` you can use this test:

```
=LOOKUP(A2;Sheet!A:A;Sheet2!A:A)=A2
```

The complete formula should be (to take into account non-existing values):

```
=IF(LOOKUP(A2;Sheet!A:A;Sheet2!A:A)=A2;=LOOKUP(A2;Sheet!A:A;Sheet2!B:B);"")
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Even `=LOOKUP(A2;Sheet!A:A)` doesn't return the same value as `A2`. The values in the column contain many `\` in their name . Should it make any difference?

Comment: The editor didn't put the char right - should be '\'. For example values look like \asd4\asd3\asd2\asd1

Comment: Issue sorted by sorting the vector range.

Comment: The function `LOOKUP` demans sorted lists. The function `VLOOKUP` can also be used with unsorted lists. [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)