# Retrieval of values of more than two columns in an another sheet using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Three column data set of 50,000 students  in Sheet 1 as follows :

Sheet 1

```
Column A  Column B    Column C   
23        Ram           567
24        Shyam         678
25        Sharma        634
```

Column A is the ID of the student, Column B is the Name , Column C is the Marks scored in a subject 
Now I want to have another sheet say sheet 2 where as soon as I enter the ID and it will automatically retrieve the corresponding values from the sheet 1.

Sheet 2

```
Column A  Column B    Column C   
23
```

Comment: Please explore the formula vlookup

Comment: While `Vlookup` might be the more known, `INDEX` & `MATCH` is the prefered method. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194) post to start familiarize yourself with this combination of functions. It also has an example which your can prety much use 1-on-1