# Get the content of a column based on the column value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

By checking the value in  answer column it should return content from that column 
 here answer is C so it should get Delhi from column C and put it in output column

---

### Sample

[image]

Comment: checkout   =Hlookup()

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to do it not sure

Comment: How `Output` is `Delhi`? In `D column` it is showing `none of the above`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Davesexcel stated, it seems HLOOKUP could work.

Here is a Google Sheet using HLOOKUP with a formula that should work in Excel as well: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LaCqkcLpgiQ1cYZEUBSSYbJkOaht1A34Af1MlZJwIc0/edit?usp=sharing.

The formula I have as an example is:

=hlookup(F2,B1:E2,row())

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Index(), Match()` combine, which are better than `Vlookup(), HLookup()`.

```
=INDEX(B2:E2,,MATCH(F2,B1:E1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I agree on the ["better"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194) aspect. HLookup is just the more known one.

Comment: Yes, depends on user choice.Goal is to solve the issue.