# Excel: How can I get price from sheet B where product_id is identical product_id in sheet A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in my excel

Sheet A

```
id  | name   | price
123 | Towel  |
456 | Can    |
789 | Mirror |
```

Sheet B

```
id  | price
789 | 3.99
123 | 15.12
456 | 0.99
```

Now I need a formula, which sets the correct price in column `price` in sheet A, by using id as identifyer. So `id` is the reference.
My amateurish theory would be something like this:

```
Get price From sheet B where id = id in this row (sheet A)
```

This "formula" would be placed in each price field in sheet A

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks

Comment: Though `VLookup` is the more "known" approach, however `INDEX` and `MATCH` is the "better" approach. For some basic understanding, you could for example have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a VLOOKUP for this purpose. It can search for the ID in the second sheet and return a specified column.

You can find the documentation here:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1