# Excel - 2 sheets - Sheet A & B has multiple rows, need to search sheet B for phrases found in sheet A and copy another cell over

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have 2 sheets:-

Sheet A has description (column B) and sales price (column C), Sheet B has identical columns, description (Column B) and purchase price (Column A). However Sheet B have 1000 lines and Sheet A have only 50 lines.

I want to get the purchase price from Sheet B to Sheet A using the description as the commonality

So

Sheet A column B has the descriptions and column C the sales price.
Sheet B column B has the descriptions and column C the purchase price

I need a formula or script that will look through each row on sheet B looking in column B to find the match with the cell in column B of sheet A and then copy the value from column C in sheet B to the correct row cell in column D in sheet A

I will then have 1 sheet with a number of products that shows sales and purchase price based on the description

Any ideas welcome

Mak

Comment: Have you tried  VLOOKUP https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: What you describe is literally the VLOOKUP function :-)

Comment: What you want is either `VLOOKUP`, but try get in the habit of using a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194) is a short explanation why.