# Select a Cell in a row where a match is found in same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to fill a cell from a row if a match is found in an other TAB.

In this example, I want to fill NAME Column if I find the ID in TAB2. So basically, formula would be:
If I find ID in TAB2, then fill NAME from TAB2 in TAB1..

```
TAB1
------------------------------------
| ID             | NAME            |
------------------------------------
| 12245          | ERIC            |
| 12246          |                 |
| 12247          |                 |
| 12248          | JANE            |


TAB2
------------------------------------
| ID             | NAME            |
------------------------------------
| 12245          | ERIC            |
| 12248          | JANE            |
```

I hope I made myself clear...

Comment: Many examples around on how to `VLOOKUP` or combo of `INDEX`+`MATCH`, even the new `XLOOKUP` is a possibility. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194) explaination.

Comment: Something like `=INDEX(TAB2!A:B,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A2,TAB2!A:A),0),2)` should work. You can wrap in an IF to get a specific value if the ID name doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, both of you. Very sad that my version does not support xlookup because this is awesome !