# Match Cells on Sheet 1 & 2 and return value from a cell on Sheet 2 to a new cell on Sheet 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, export-to-excel

Im trying to copy data from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Example

```
Sheet 1
UNIT_ID    CC    PP
1001       100   200
1002       200   300

Sheet 2
UNIT_ID    CC                    PP
1001       SHEET1 data           SHEET1 data
1001       ""                    ""
1001       ""                    ""
1001       ""                    ""
1002       ""                    ""
1002       ""                    ""
1002       ""                    ""
```

how can I do this task? any expert advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Research either `VLOOKUP` or how to combine both `INDEX` and `MATCH` to return those values from Sheet1. There are plenty of questions/answers out here on SO that cover this topic. For example have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58436658/9758194)

Comment: How did you get 100 and how did you get 200 on sheet 1, Since they are not listed in the sheet 2 data? Same would go for 200 and 300.  If they are part of the data on Sheet 2, you need to adjust your sample data.   If I am miss understanding this it may be because your question and title are opposite in terms of the direction you are copying.

Comment: Q1) "Match cells on sheet 1 & 2" *Which cells? Unit ID (Sheet 1) = Unit ID (Sheet 2)? How to treat multiple matches?  what is the lookup value ("Sheet 1 data"?)*  2) "return cell from Sheet 2" *which cell? In col Unit_ID? Or under CC/PP? or somewhere else? +Q: match back to Unit ID in Sheet 1 (e.g. adjacent to PP)?*.  Q3) "Trying to copy data from sheet 1 to sheet 2" *But in the heading your desc. suggests that you ultimately end up in Sheet 1 - is it the other way around?*.  *Overall: show expected output (e.g. screenshot).  Clarify exactly what you want to do.  Clarify "Sheet 1 Data".*

Comment: Review this source once more (you should have a link to this/similar in your inbox upon joining - but could've been spam/filtered inadvertently) https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask